# Simple installed tool for digital Scrum Board

Tags: scrum, scrumboard

I am looking for a basic and simple-to-install digital version of a Scrum board.

- I do prefer physical index cards, but in this case logistics makes it hard. Thus, I need to have it on the computer.
- No real need to share data between several clients. To us it is enough if it runs on one single machine.
- Just need basic functionality. A drag-drop board and a sprint burndown would do fine.
- Due to regularly constraints I cannot use an online SaaS, must keep the data local.
- Time is short, so simple install and ready-to-go.
- Does not need to be free, but of course price is interesting.

I have not had this set of constraints earlier, so I am unfamiliar.

I have done some research and have some general experience. For example VersionOne, Mingle and Hansoft seem to have a good reputation. Anyone can comment on how those fit the above list? Anyone have other recommendations?

Answer (score 6):

This thread is a bit old now, but leaving my find in the hope to help others searching the same topic.

If you are looking for a simple tool for developers to collaborate on a Scrum project, **http://trello.com/** is very simple and intuitive. Absolutely no clutter and easily lets a small team manage their cards.

Comment: To the person who down-voted this: would really help to see your reasons for it, if it wasn't just for fun. Trello isn't an offline tool (as OP asked) but is a real help as a scrum board. I've even mentioned that the comment is being made because of the search relevance of this query.

Comment: +1 Worked with it, forgot about it, it's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at Atlassian Jira with the GreenHopper plugin - it has a nice dashboard.
http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/

Comment: I feel greenhopper is trying to fit a square peg (jira) into a round hole (scrum) [/editorial]

Comment: I've found it to work rather well. You can work almost entirely with the hole, but have the peg if you need it. And the two are not as incompatible as a square and a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mingle from ThoughtWorks](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management/features-benefits). A really great tool. Wall looks like [this](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/sites/files/studios/images/Card%20walls-%20A%20shared%20workspace.png)

Free download/install for 1 year / 5 users.

Answer (score 0):

Excel (or OpenOffice) spreadsheet? Why do you need a special tool for this?

Comment: I have a link for templates for both excel and hosted google docs burn down charts.  It is such a simple way to manage tasks and with the google docs versions, team members can update their progress and be more involved with the entire project as a whole. [Click here to go to the article - Burn Down Chart Tutorial: Simple Agile Project Tracking](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/burn-down-charts-tutorial-simple-agile-project-tracking/)

Comment: Then don't comment, post an answer!

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:i3AaHvRVKhYJ:joel.inpointform.net/software-development/burn-down-charts-tutorial-simple-agile-project-tracking/+&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl site in link of @i8abug is broken, here is the google cache link. The google docs links are broken but you can still download the excelsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar decision to make a year ago and went for Version One Team Edition - which is free.

http://www.versionone.com/Product/Compare_Editions.asp

It's easy to deploy the SQL database wherever you want it - so locally in your case. 
Our team found using the software easy and intuitive.

The free version (up to 10 users) has ample features - the sprints/stories/tasks are easy to setup and view. The burndown chart is good.

All in all, I've no regrets with choosing Verison One - it's easy to install, easy to use and free.